# android reminder and task app tutorial

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar, reminders

I am newer to Android and am in search of a tutorial to make a reminder/task app that allows a user to set a repeating reminder (repeat daily, weekly) and sends a notification a set period of minutes before the event time.

Has anyone had any luck locating such a tutorial?
Thank you,.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of examples, just google it.
For example, http://sourceforge.net/projects/birthreminder/